# Correlation between random variables

Tags: random-variables, independence, covariance, correlation

I have the following problem: given a random variable $X \sim \mathcal{N} \left( 0, 1 \right)$ (i.e. given a standard normally distributed random variable), I want to calculate the correlation between $X$ and $X^{2}$. Therefore i proceed in the following way:

\begin{equation}
\varrho_{X, X^{2}} = \frac{cov \left( X, X^{2} \right) }{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{X^2}} = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[ (X - 0) (X^{2} - 1) \right]}{1 \cdot 2} = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left( X^{3} - X \right)}{2}.
\end{equation}

Can anyone help me further?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hint: If $X$ and $-X$ have equal distribution then also $X^3$ and $-X^3=(-X)^3$ have equal distribution. Draw conclusions for $\mathbb EX^3$.

Comment: It is 0, of course (and from the definition of expected value I can split $\mathbb{E} (X^{3} - X)$ into $\mathbb{E} [X^{3}] - \mathbb{E} [X]$). Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed. Actually it is enough to prove that $\text{Cov}(X,X^2)=0$. Then consequently $\rho_{X,X^2}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall $\mathbb{E} [X^3-X] = \mathbb{E}[X^3]-\mathbb{E}[X]$. Now $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$, while 
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^3] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} x^3 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx.$$
Integrating by parts, it turns out that $\mathbb{E}[X^3] = 0$, and hence $ \varrho_{X,X^2} = 0. $

Comment: Indeed, but integration is fortunately not needed here. Since $X^3$ and $-X^3$ have equal distribution we have $\mathbb EX^3=-\mathbb EX^3$, so it must be $0$ (provided that the expectation exists, which is indeed the case).